# Number of objects subject to condition from outer query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, `event` and `registration`. The setup is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE events_event (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    title character varying(80) NOT NULL,
    location character varying(80) NOT NULL,
    description text NOT NULL,
    date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    available_from timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    capacity integer NOT NULL,
    bus_available boolean NOT NULL,
    register_others boolean NOT NULL,
    only_members boolean NOT NULL,
    vegan_available boolean NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE events_registration (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    timestamp timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    event_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES events_event(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    user_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES authentication_customuser(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    is_vegan boolean NOT NULL,
    uses_bus boolean NOT NULL
);
```

The capacity represents how many registrations can be accepted to the event, and any registrations beyond that are considered to be on a waiting list.
I would like to get number of bus registrations, and vegan registrations that are within the capacity constraints, per event. If I were not to consider the capacity constraints, the number of vegan people per event would be:

```
SELECT e.id, COUNT(r.is_vegan)
FROM events_event e
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT event_id, is_vegan
    FROM events_registration
) r ON e.id = r.event_id
GROUP BY e.id
```

but this counts all registrations, including ones that do not consider the capacity constraints. Is this possible within SQL?

Comment: I don't understand this capacity thing. Capacity of what? Do you mean you want to count the number of registrations, but if that number is higher than the capacity, you want to show the capacity instead?  And how does is_vegan come into play? In your query you can replace the subquery with a mere `LEFT JOIN events_registration b`. And COUNT(b.is_vegan)` is the same number as `COUNT(b.event_id)`, i.e. the number of registrations. And why do you use alias names a and b? Are you trying to confuse the reader? You could use e for event and r for registration or something else appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, what I would like to do is count the registrations with ´is_vegan=true´ that are within the capacity constraints, per event

Comment: So if the number of registrations <= capacity return the number of registrations else return the capacity? If that’s not what you mean then please update your question with some sample date and the result you want to achieve from that data

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you'll just count and then compare with the capacity and show the lesser value of the two:

```
SELECT e.id, LEAST(COUNT(r.id), e.capacity) as vegans
FROM events_event e
LEFT JOIN events_registration r ON r.event_id = e.id AND r.is_vegan
GROUP BY e.id
ORDER BY e.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the approach from @thorsten-kettner and include a count for bus registrants as well:

```sql
SELECT e.id
  , LEAST(COUNT(r.id) FILTER (WHERE r.is_vegan), e.capacity) as vegans
  , LEAST(COUNT(r.id) FILTER (WHERE r.uses_bus), e.capacity) as uses_bus
FROM events_event e
LEFT JOIN events_registration r ON r.event_id = e.id
GROUP BY e.id
ORDER BY e.id;
```